# Sqlite3 datetime and julianDay function's don't recognize midnight hour and minute

Tags: sqlite

> sqlite> select datetime('2022-02-10 01:02:03');

> 2022-02-10 01:02:03

> sqlite> select datetime('2022-02-10 0:00:00');

> sqlite> select julianDay('2022-02-10 01:02:03');

> 2459620.54309028

> sqlite> select julianDay('2022-02-10 0:00:00');

Answer (score 0):

Needs 00 instead of a single 0 for hour.

Comment: Not only for the hour. SQLite's datetime functions work only with the iso format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` for text timestamps.